Using symfony forms,im missing a html tag, why is this happening?
So the issue is only the first element from this for loop is missing the  tags around the delete button, all other elements work fine and have the  tags,i cant figure out why...any ideas?
Browser inspector: https://prnt.sc/5kxKQ23j8kqw
<tbody>
{% for taskForm in form.tasks %}
  {{ form_widget(taskForm.id) }}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ form_widget(taskForm.title) }}</td>
    <td>{{ form_widget(taskForm.content) }}</td>
    <td>{{ form_widget(taskForm.date) }}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{ form_widget(taskForm.finished) }}</td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <form action="{{ path('app_task_delete', {id: taskForm.id.vars.value}) }}" method="post">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">DELETE</button>
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>

This is the form for a single task
TaskFormType
$builder
    ->add('id', HiddenType::class, ['required' => false, 'disabled' => true])
    ->add('title', TextType::class, [
        'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control'],
        'constraints' => [
            new NotBlank([
                'message' => 'Please enter a title',
            ]),
        ],
    ])
    
    ->add('content', TextType::class, [
        'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control'],
        'required' => false,
    ])
    ->add('date', DateTimeType::class, [
        'mapped' => true,
        'widget' => 'single_text',
        'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control'],
        'required' => false,
    ]);
    if ($options['finished_checkbox']) {
        $builder   
        ->add('finished', CheckboxType::class, [
            'mapped' => true,
            'required' => false,
        ]);
    }
;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
{
$resolver->setDefaults([
    'data_class' => TodoTask::class,
    'finished_checkbox' => false,
]);
}

I list the tasks with this formBuilder.
TaskList
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('tasks', CollectionType::class, [
        'entry_type' => TaskFormType::class,
        'entry_options' => [
            'finished_checkbox' => true,
        ],
    ]);
}


You can not output arbitrary other elements between tbody and tr, that is invalid HTML.
